# $1 в регулярном выражении

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте.
Есть допустим текст:

```
bla13 blach13
rgf13 dsfg13
```

И нужно что-то вроде

```
preg_match_all('|([a-z]{3})([0-9]{2})\ ([a-z]{4})$2|Us',.....
```

То есть во время поиска чтобы было совпадение двух искомых.
Пробовал по разному но никак, а у гугла не знаю как спросить.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

Не понятно что именно Вы хотите.
Рассмотрю два варианта. Например Вы хотите сократить длину регулярного выражения употребив повторяющуюся часть. В таком случае рекомендую почитать про именованные группы- с именами удобнее работать, чем с цифрами.

```
|(?P<str1>[a-z]{3})(?P<num1>[0-9]{2}) ([a-z]{4})(?P>num1)|Us
```

Выражение `(?P>num1)` просто произведет в это место подстановку выражения `num1`, то есть будут найдены совпадения для обоих строк текста

```
bla13 blach13
rgf77 dsfg88
```

Теперь рассмотрим другой вариант- Вам необходимо, чтобы точное текстовое совпадение некоторой группы встретилось второй раз

```
|(?P<str1>[a-z]{3})(?P<num1>[0-9]{2}) ([a-z]{4})\k<num1>|Us
```

А вот тут поведение изменится- теперь требуется, чтобы вместо `\k<num1>` стояли точно такие же цифры, как и были в группе `num1`. То есть для двух строк текста выше совпадет только первая строка, так как во второй цифры разные.

Comment: А если все же нужно прямо цифрами, то нужно писать не

    |([a-z]{3})([0-9]{2})\ ([a-z]{4})$2|Us

а 

    |([a-z]{3})([0-9]{2})\ ([a-z]{4})\2|Us

Подставновка найденной подстроки в самом выражении должна выглядеть как `\1`, `\2` и т. д. А вот для строки замены — для `preg_replace('/expression_here/', '$1')` — здесь да, здесь `$1`

Comment: @VladD, Хм, а что не так?

Comment: @VladD, так это обратная ссылка, а так ?P<num1> это объявление группы.

Comment: @ReinRaus: виноват, ушёл стыдиться в угол и курить документацию.

Answer (score 1):

Есть регулярка:

```
/a(bc)[\S\s]+a\1[\S\s]+/
```

`\1` - это первое совпадение, в данном случае - "bс".
т.е. для этой регулярки подойдет строка вида "a**bc**d a**bс**fsdg"

Возможно это вам как то поможет решить вашу проблему.
А `$1` как выше правильно подметили используется в `replace` выражениях.